# datanucleus/JDO a relation to many different classes)

Tags: java, metadata, jdo, datanucleus

I need to create a database with 2 kinds of 'modules'.

> 1. domain focused classes
> 2. metadata classes

In the first group it is just simple (or complex rather) RDBMS. The second 'block' are metadata classes which collects information about classes from the first block.

What I have done:

1. Created Entity class which is parent of all fro 1st part:

   ```
   @PersistenceAware
   @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.NEW_TABLE)
   public abstract class Entity implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   }
   ```
2. Created normal schema with all entities inherit somehow `Entity` class.
3. Created `InternalMapping` class as a parent of the whole concept.

   ```
   @PersistenceCapable
   @Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceStrategy.NEW_TABLE) 
   public abstract class InternalMapping implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
   private Entity entity;
   //.. cut off getter and setter
   }
   ```
4. Created `InternalMapping` child which should have that feature.

Finally I found it does not work. Probably because Entity does not have any field. But if so I would expect 2 fields: `a primary key` and `class name`. In that way I would map every entity by 2 coordinates: `ID` and `class name`.

Any idea how to solve that issue? An finally how `JDOQL` would looks like.

**Ps**. I know that `RDBMS` is not the best solution for that kind of problems but people with whom I work wish to have relational database.

Comment: Many thanks guys for text editions. Looks much better.

Comment: *what* doesn't work? creating the schema? in which case what does the log say? JDOQL for what? Where is this "class name" coming from? you haven't defined a discriminator

Comment: Created schema does not have proper fields on the InternalMapping side. However I thought about that and probably found solution for that using AOP. I will describe more tomorrow after tests.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution for my problem. I am able to keep entities of different classes keep in one table. Also I am able to do JDOQL request with filtering instances of particular class.

The example is inside GitHub repository here: https://github.com/jgrzebyta/samples-jdo/tree/metalink and within `metalink` branch. It is slightly modified *Tutorial* project from *datanucleus* example.

So.

The lowest level in the inheritance hierarchy is `Core` interface with the PK defined inside.

Class `MyIndex` collects different implementations of the `Core` interface, i.e. `Book` and `Product`. Also I have added new column called `type` for storing `Class` names only. I am able to retrieve implementations of `Core` interface and build query filter against `type` filed because query type `core instanceof Book` simple does not work. That is the feature of the `identity` mapping strategy which I have used in my solution: [DataNucleus JDO Objects](http://www.datanucleus.org/products/datanucleus/jdo/orm/objects.html).

PS. If you run command `mvn -Pschema-gen compile` than you will receive `DDL` file.